# Is it possible to capture the value prior to an input type insertReplacementText event in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

When an `insertReplacementText` input event type, as defined in this [W3C Editor's Draft](https://rawgit.com/w3c/input-events/v1/index.html#interface-InputEvent-Attributes), takes place on a textarea element, the `data` property or attribute provides the text that was added to the textarea value, replacing some other text, such as when right-click on a misspelled word and the context menu provides suggested words.

The misspelled word does not have to be selected first; and, if the textarea has the focus (the cursor could be far from the misspelled word), when the right click takes place, the cursor is not moved at all.

After the replacement, the cursor is positioned to the right of the new text, as in a paste event. The difficulty is determining the length of the text that was replaced and or it's value.

I ask because I'd like to capture the needed information to undo/redo this event.

Thank you.

Update:
If you maintain a copy of the last value of the textarea in RAM or other lcoal storage options, then there is a way to accomplish this; although the event itself provides little data. I was rather stupid at first, as I was testing this in a separate piece of code, because I forgot that, in the code of my particular project, there is always in RAM a copy of the last value in the textarea. Having that information makes this operation very similar to a paste event when there is a selection before the paste that is replaced by the pasted text. After the replacement is performed, the cursor is positioned immediately to the right of the last character of the replacement text. The data property of the insertReplacementText event contains the value of the inserted text.

Thus, it is a matter of arithmetic involving the length of the new text, the difference in the length of the previous copy of the textarea value's length and the length of the DOM element's value after replacement, and the cursor position after the replacement has been performed. The difference in the length's of the textarea values is the difference in the length of the old text and new text. This provides the selection range from which to extract the old text from the saved copy before updating the copy to the new value. The selectionStart is the same for both the old text and new text; the difference is in the selectionEnd based on the lengths, if not equal.

As long as the browser keeps positioning the cursor to the right of the last character of the replacement text, and you maintain a copy of the last value of the textarea, it appears that this ought to work.

Thank you.

Comment: Right before any code that does this: `myTextArea.dispatchEvent(insertReplacementText)`, you could call a function (or dispatch another event) that does this: `myTextArea.setAttribute("data-old-value", myTextArea.value)`. (Btw, it's not clear whether this is this a custom event that you created or if there is documentation for it somewhere.)

Comment: I added a link to the documentation of the browser event, for it's not custom. Thanks for the response. I don't think it can be done like that because the `insertReplacementText` event fires only after the text has been replaced. I'm using Firefox which doesn't have a `beforeinput` event; but, for this event, it appears that wouldn't help because there's no selection required. The right-click grabs the word. Perhaps, that is the answer. Use mousedown, event.button=2, and to do the same, and capture the word if possible before mouseup triggers the replacement event.

Comment: I should've made it clear also that I'm trying to get the word replaced and it's position, `selectionStart` and/or `selectionEnd`, not the entire value in the textarea . Your thought of copying the entire value could work, even without a trigger off of the `insertReplacementText` event, as long as a copy is carried along at all times and updated after each event. It is an option, I guess.

Comment: Don't add the solution to your question, please. Post it as answer instead.

Comment: It's not really a solution but something that works for my code since it maintains a backup copy of the textarea value. If one's code doesn't keep a backup copy, then the events (at least in Firefox without a beforeinput) don't appear to provide a solution. However, that's just where I and my experience stopped, since I had a way to get what I needed apart from a "real event" answer. Somebody might know of a better method; only 35 people looked at the question at this point. I'll edit my update to make it clear that I didn't come up with a real solution.